# Excel VBA: Part of code only runs when stepping through. Does not run if called from other subroutine or when continuing

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a chart formatting Excel add-in for my office.
To handle both embedded charts and chart sheets I wrote two loops in the first subroutine. Each time a chart is activated, a second subroutine is called to handle `ActiveChart` formatting.

Part of my goal is to apply data labels to line charts, however my code produces blank data labels as in figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBmPM.png) even when I have set `DataLabel.ShowSeriesName = True`. There are two cases where the labels are added correctly described below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CESAR_style ()
Dim a as application
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim chtO As ChartObject
Dim cht As Chart

Set twb = ThisWorkbook
Set a = Application

' Turn off events
a.EnableEvents = False

' Loop through all chart sheets
For Each cht In a.Charts
  cht.Activate
  Call Format
Next

' Loop through all chart objects
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  For Each chtO In ws.ChartObjects
    chtO.Activate
    Call Format
  Next
Next

a.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Format()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

With ActiveChart
    ' Count the series in the chart
    i = .SeriesCollection.Count

    ' Code here to add a new series used to make a 'Today' _
      reference line dividing history and future

    ' Add series data labels, excluding the new series added above
    ' For each data series
    For j = 1 To i
        With .FullSeriesCollection(j)
            ' For Line charts
            If .ChartType = xlLine Then
                ' Turn off leader lines for full series
                .HasLeaderLines = False

            ' Add series data label to right of last point in series
                With .Points(.Points.Count)
                    ' If a label already exists remove it
                    If .HasDataLabel = True Then
                       .HasDataLabel = False
                    Else
                    End If
```

The code works properly to this point, but when `.ApplyDataLabels` runs, it creates blank data labels as seen in figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBmPM.png) [blank data labels][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBmPM.png)

```
                    ' Add a series data label
                    .ApplyDataLabels ShowSeriesName:=True, _
                            ShowValue:=False, _
                            HasLeaderLines:=False
                End With

            Else
            ' Code here to handle stacked area charts; working properly
            End If
        End With
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

I have added a break point at `.ApplyDataLabels`. If I continue the code with F5 or the play button, it continues to give me blank labels. However, if i step the code with F8 or Step Into, the code executes successfully and I get the labels I want as seen in figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsjU6.png).
[Correct data labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsjU6.png)

A second confusing quality is when I move the `.ApplyDataLabels` segment to the CESAR_style subroutine, the code runs successfully.

I have tried delaying the code with `sleep` but without success.

Is there something I'm doing wrong in how I've set up the two subroutines?

Any help or insight is much appreciated. Let me know if additional information is needed to make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally with VBA I find that if something works when you're stepping through it, but not when you're running it, it's a select/focus problem. When you're stepping through the code, you're likely selecting the worksheet the the chart is on so you can see what your code is doing, which is effectively doing a step for your macro. Try activating the worksheet the chart is on before activating the chart. If that doesn't work, try selecting a cell on the worksheet instead.